# Import comma delimted with comma space qualifier

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, delimiter, qualifiers

How can I import a comma delimited text file with the following example record:
abc, def and ghi,jkl

such that I get the output as 
column1: abc, def and ghi
column2: jkl

There is no text qualifier surrounding (abc, def and ghi), and if the comma and space (, ) is specified as the text qualifier in sql server import, it does not produce the above result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Bulk Insert [MSDN: Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

```
    USE tempdb;
    GO

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #test;
    CREATE TABLE #test
    (
     col1 VARCHAR(50)
    ,col2 VARCHAR(50)
    )

    BULK INSERT #test
    From 'C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\test.csv'
    WITH
    (
     FIRSTROW = 2
    ,FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'
    ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )

    Select  * 
    From    #test
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #test;
```

Below is the layout of my csv file. Would it be possible to use pipe delimited or some other kind of delimiter like ™...My favorite ;)

col1|col2

abc, def and ghi| jkl

And the results of the import.

```
               col1                 col2
               abc, def and ghi     jkl
```

Comment: Note that the OP needs the `,` embedded inside field1 to not be treated as a separator, so I am not sure your solution is going to work out of the box.